# Is $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N)$ a set without axiom of choice?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $M$ and $N$ be $A$-modules, $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N)$ the set of all $A$-module homomorphisms $M\rightarrow N$. $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N)$ can be viewed as a subset of the cartesian product $\prod_{m\in M}N$. But doesn't it require axiom of choice for $\prod_{m\in M}N$ to be a set? Is there a chance that $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N)$ may be a set without axiom of choice?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fact that $\prod_{m\in M} N$ is a set holds regardless of the Axiom of Choice. A product of a family of sets is *always* a set in ZF, you don't need AC for that. What the Axiom of Choice might play a role in doing is telling you whether the product is *empty* or not.

However, in the case of modules, you can prove the product is not empty *without* the Axiom of Choice. This, because modules have a distinguished element (the zero element), so if $\{N_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a nonempty family of modules, then $\prod_{i\in I}N_i$ is necessarily nonempty: it contains the function $f\colon I\to \cup N_i$ with $f(i)=0$ for all $i$.

Moreover, even for sets, one can show that an arbitrary *power* of a nonempty set is nonempty without the Axiom of Choice. Meaning, if $A$ is a nonempty set and $I$ is a nonempty set, then $\prod_{i\in I}A\neq\emptyset$ holds in ZF, even without choice: since $A$ is nonempty, there exists $a\in A$; define $f\colon I\to A$ by $f(i)=a$ for all $i$, and this shows the product is nonempty.

And so $\mathrm{Hom}_A(M,N)$ is a set, regardless of anything else; and moreover, it is provably nonempty, since the function $f\colon M\to N$ given by $f(m)=0$ for all $m$ lies in the set.

Comment: I almost got ahead of you this time :-)

Comment: @Asar: Had the question been posted five minutes later, you would have. I'm off to teach for two hours now... (-:

Comment: Shame. Oh well, enjoy teaching. :-)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. My brain was a little short of oxygen when I was writing that question.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the set theory of ZF, it is a set.

Since $M$ is a set and $N$ is a set, we have that $f\colon M\to N$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(M\times N)$. The latter, is a set by the axiom of the power set.

Now we can define (using $A$ as a parameter, of course) all the maps which has a certain property, and by the axiom schema of replacement (or subset, if you want) it is indeed a set.

Without the axiom of choice, however, the product *may* be empty. The empty set, however, is still a set. Although in algebraic structures this is often not the case, since $m\mapsto 0_N$ is a homomorphism, and it certainly exists.